# Ubuntu Software RAID server and VMware conversion tool

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, raid, rsync

I have tried to find an answer to this, through several unsuccessful forum searches. I have a Hosted Virtual Private Ubuntu Server that I have no physical access to. I downloaded VMware's vCenter Converter Standalone (Version 6.0.0 build 2716716) and have attempted to connect to my remote Hosted Virtual thru this application, in which is does make an connection to the machine, however, I have never been past an error message saying the boot partition is not mounted, and upon research into that issue, I have come across a VMware article that its not currently possible to use VMwares converter tool across a machine with software RAID. So I feel I need to go a different route. Does anyone have experience using something such as an RSYNC copy of the entire remote server, then take that RSYNC of all the files, and somehow make that into an image file, and convert that to a VMK or Virtual image that can be mounted into a VMWARE host, even if its converting into a VIRTUALBOX image then convert it to a WMware Image?Any advise would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!